# Logging from mappers into one location

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to know what mappers are doing at the given moment. From my understanding all of them are writing StdOut to a local log file. It's not practical to tail multiple log files on many servers. I would like to make all mappers write into one place instead (like a specific path on HDFS).

Is there any build-in feature or external library which can help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of external library, you can use **Flume** (https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html) to transfer all these logs to a centralized location, either HDFS or a local file.

Basically on all machines, flume agents will run and do a 'tail -f' on the log files and transfer them to a central location.